# Virtual Network Interface in monitor mode linux (mimic of iw command)

Tags: c++, c, networking

I am currently trying to create a virtual network interface that hooks into wlan0 and creates a version of wlan0 called mon0...
Basically what `airmon-ng start wlan0` or `iw dev wlan0 interface add mon0 type monitor` does.

However, I will soon not have access to these commands within my program so I am trying to figure out how create it myself but I am not sure where to start. If someone could help get me started that would be appreciated.

Just for a little background, I have a c++ program using libpcap to parse certain packets but I am now migrating to a different system.

Thank you,
DO

Comment: Did you find out the solution ? There is something called TUN/TAP for simulation of network interfaces. Check it out. Don't have the details.

Comment: http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/
Try working with this.